# How to extract filenames from a chunk of code

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I want to extract all the filenames which are coming in a piece of code like

```
a=`cut -d: -f 3 /etc/passwd | sort | uniq` | awk `{print $2}`
"if [ -n "$a" ];",
"then for i in `echo "$a"`; do awk -F:
...
;done; else echo "error";fi" cat /etc/issue ... 
/etc/pam.d/system-auth
(/deny=/)
```

Like in this code, I want to fetch these files -
/etc/passwd, /etc/issue and /etc/pam.d/system-auth

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: There are **many** valid filenames in your sample data: `a`, `cut`, `/etc/passwd`, `sort`, `uniq`, `awk`, `print` in the first line alone. You will need to be more specific about what you want to extract.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are interested in absolute paths that start with a slash, you can use following regex to capture,

```
\/[\w+.\/-]+(?= |$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xz76ga/1)

You may put your text in a file say myfile and then run this command,

```
cat myfile|grep -oP '\/[\w+.\/-]+(?= |$)'
```

OR

```
grep -oP '\/[\w+.\/-]+(?= |$)' myfile
```

This prints following output as the way you want,

```
/etc/passwd
/etc/issue
/etc/pam.d/system-auth
```